# Microsoft Excel drag to create formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Microsoft Excel I am trying to drag to create formulas in multiple cells.  When I type in:

```
=J1+K1
```

and drag down, all cells get updated accordingly:

```
=J2+K2
=J3+K3
```

I have another cell that is:

```
=E1-(OtherTab!B7)
```

When I drag it down, I get:

```
=E2-(OtherTab!B8)
=E3-(OtherTab!B9)
```

I want it to keeps (OtherTab!B7) on all cells.  So it should be:

```
=E2-(OtherTab!B7)
=E3-(OtherTab!B7)
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it absolute with `$`

```
=E1-(OtherTab!$B$7)
```

Comment: Yup that's it! Came here to post this same answer